# How to prevent a derived class being an abstract class in c++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have a question about Polymorphism. The following example would result in a error of **"cannot declare variable ‘obj’ to be of abstract type ‘B’"**

I know that the problems lies in the pure virtual method of function A::foo(), which make A an abstract class. Furthermore, class B inherent from class A. If i didn't implement the method foo() in the body of B, does that necessarily make B an abstract as well? and hence causing the error? But what's the logic of this? There might be a lot other derived classes from my base class A, the function foo might be applicable in some derived class, but may be totally useless for Class B. Of course I can declare an empty function B::foo() which absolutely does nothing and make the code run. But, is there any better solution or explanation of this behavior? Thanks!

```
struct A
{
    A() : x(0)  {}
    virtual int foo() const = 0;   // if I remove this line, code will run with no problem.
    int x;
};

struct B :  A {};

int main()
{
    B obj;
    cout << obj.x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't do that, you must implement foo(). Or make foo() an empty function in class A that does nothing, and keep virtual keyword to override it in your child class if you need it.

Comment: If `foo` does not makes sense for `B`, it's time to rethink the design. Something that only makes sense for some derived classes does not belong in the base.

Comment: If you want to prevent object creation of class `A` and allow all of the derived classes to be created, then you can make constructor of the class `A` protected or make it `private` and  make the derived class a friend of the base class.

Comment: Side note,  don't forget the virtual destructor in A...

Comment: @abhiarora A protected constructor is fine, a private one (in general) a rather bad idea, it would require to modify the base class any time you add a new derived one...

Comment: Agree @Aconcagua. `protected` should be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, you are right, not implementing `foo` in `A` makes `A` abstract, not implementing `foo` in `B` makes that one abstract as well.

The whole sense of polymorphism is that you provide a common interface for a set of classes. Any derived type can behave as a base type in general, the specific behaviour would deviate only in the details (e. g. like steering in a car, bike or ship, the mechanism is different, but you *can* steer all of them).

If it doesn't make sense to call `foo` on `B`, then first ask *'Why?'*! Somehow, `B` cannot be a true `A` then, just like a screw driver cannot be a hammer (but both can be tools).

If you find yourself in such trouble, then most likely your design is flawed.

Comment: thanks for the example, i think it's a great answer

Answer (score 3):

Class `A` is abstract because `foo()=0`.
If you derive from `A`, you need to implement this `foo()`, else the derived class is still abstract.
So class `B` has to have

```
int foo() const override {}
```

To be able to be used as object

You could probably declare this function private, to not have it accessible... but the question is why `B` is derived from `A` if or doesn't implement `foo()`. Maybe you need to rethink your design.. maybe should move `foo()=0` to a separate interface class, and implement multiple inheritance.

```
Class C : public A, public FooInterface {
public:
    int foo() const override {};
};
```

Alternatively you could implement an `AwithFoo` class that derives from `A` but adds `foo()`. I.e. add some hierarchy.

```
class A {}
class B : public A {}
class AwithFoo : public A {
public:
    using A::A; // a way to inherit the constructor.
    virtual int foo() const = 0;
}
class C : public AwithFoo {
public:
    int foo() const override {};
}
```

Although this latter solution is not always a good solution. It will add extra layers of indirection.

Comment: @Aconcagua yes, that's what I'm trying to say with `FooInterface`==your `D`...

Comment: Oh, seem to have been blind ;)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't depend on classed that provide you with functionality that you don't need. If you do that you violate [liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). That`s a bad design and will lead you to many problems such as [refused bequest](https://refactoring.guru/smells/refused-bequest).

If however you need that functionality and inherit from a base class you have to either implement that function or leave it abstract which will make the derived class abstract as well.